# The time stamp counter of CPU on scheduler id 13 is not synchronized with other CPUs

Tags: sql-server-2008

On one of our production server, SQL Server log is continuously showing the following error:

> The time stamp counter of CPU on scheduler id 13 is not synchronized with other CPUs.

What does it mean? Is it serious? If yes, how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. It is comprehensively addressed in the Microsoft Support article:

[SQL Server timing values may be incorrect when you use utilities or technologies that change CPU frequencies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sql-server-timing-values-may-be-incorrect-when-you-use-utilities-or-technologies-that-change-cpu-frequencies-ebf5e5c7-8a31-ce81-e44a-1de75d23c8e7)

An extract:

> After you install SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2 (SP2), SQL Server logs an error message in the error log when SQL Server detects that the high resolution timers are out of sync between the CPUs. The error message indicates that performance timings may not be accurate, and users should use performance data with caution.
>
> The text of the error message resembles one of the following error messages:
>
> Error message 1
>
> > The time stamp counter of CPU on scheduler id 2 is not synchronized with other CPUs.
>
> Error message 2
>
> > CPU time stamp frequency has changed from 191469 to 1794177 ticks per millisecond. The new frequency will be used
>
> SQL Server uses the Real Time Stamp Counter (RDTSC) instruction to acquire the 64-bit CPU tick count. You can divide this value by the CPU frequency to convert the value to millisecond values. Timing variations can occur when the CPU frequency changes or drift occurs.